# How I can play rtsp video from wowza server?

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, wowza

I have a rtsp url from Wowza Media Server 2 Perpetual 2.2.4.07
How can I play it in app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use a [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://server/track.mpg"));
```

Comment: I try this it opens but 1 minute later it closed and when look at logs says me : output eos has been reached

Comment: I guess it's a problem with your video stream.

Comment: It gives me error : path = null 11-30 17:36:08.335: D/MediaPlayer(7009): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
11-30 17:36:08.335: E/MediaPlayer(7009): error (1, -2147483648)
11-30 17:36:08.380: E/MediaPlayer(7009): Error (1,-2147483648)

Answer (score 3):

This is how you start a media player with a data source. Keep in mind that android only supports certain audo/video codecs listed [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

```
MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer(); 
m.setDataSource("rtsp://rtsp.yourserver.com/stream.mp3"); 
m.prepare(); 
m.start();
```

Comment: put in a video to setDataSource and it will play a video...

Comment: no it doesnt . thanks for answering

Comment: Then your video isn't in the correct format. look http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html it says "MediaPlayer class can be used to control playback of audio/video files and streams" So I would suggest re-encoding the video to H.264